# Experience with PTFE tubing & glass connectors?

Tags: equipment

I'm wondering which PTFE tubing size to get to connect to normal 10mm OD glass connectors. For a silicon hose I would take an ID of 8-9mm as it is flexible but I think PTFE is quite rigid.

Anyone has some experience with PTFE tubing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: Do not attempt a direct connection of the PFTE hose with the glass.

Instead (assuming the tubing shall transfer gases with little pressure only):

- Because to the (compared to silicon) lesser flexibility of the tubings made from PFTE, you should consider to use glassware with threaded joints with detachable connectors. This a theme already seen with condensers, e.g.

  [image]

  ([source](https://www.coleparmer.co.uk/i/united-scientific-supplies-liebig-condenser-24-40-joint-200-mm/3450957))

  but may be equally applied to impingers

  [image]

  ([from here](https://www.dwkltd.com/en/quickfit-adapters-tubing-right-angle-1))

  or overhead exhausts:

  [image]

  ([from here](https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/quickfit-right-angle-tubing-adapter/11342035))

  These connectors may be replaced with ones made *mostly* out of PFTE, too, e.g.

  [image]

  ([source](https://www.carlroth.com/com/en/seals-hose-connectors-accessories/connectors-with-screw-cap-connectors-made-of-ptfe/p/ny37.1))

  Thus you may connect the tubing to the connector at the bench (gentle warming of the tubing with a heat gun may help), secure this end with the clip, and then mount the connected hose to the reactor.  It is faster and more secure (should you need a bit of force, damages are to the tubing and the connector, but not to the reactor) than the direct mount of the tubing to the glass.
- The other side of the PFTE tubing will connect with the metal ferrules to your gas supply, e.g.

  [image]

  (screen photo at 1:04 min from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgiGqWxSVMo))

  Depending on the dimensions, the fittings by [Swagelok](https://www.swagelok.com/en) are sold in sets of 10; a typical mechanical workshop of your university may have them already in the shelf. The less pricey Bowden connections used for 3D printers (e.g., [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbH1mzGwhdc)) are designed for compressed air.

As for any equipment working with gas: monitor the gas pressure in your reactor and use a safety release / pressure valve.